# Same form that submits to two different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am quite new to Microsoft Access but i have been working with databases for quite a while now, so I understand "the back end" (so to speak) as to how I will set up this database, but I'm not sure how to tell Access what to do and how to do it.

The aim of my database is to load up a customer's account with their information; eg, phone number address, email, etc. All this information has been migrated to a table within my new database project.

from here I would like to create a separate table which has notes which can be assigned to each user's account number. the aim of this is to be able to read up on recent activity of these customers and be able to search and filter that information on an easy to use front end interface.

So so far I have two tables, one with the customer's information in it and another which is where I would like to save the notes for each customer.

the primary key which I will be using is the customer's account numbers. This, of course, being unique to each customer and would be perfect for the primary key in both of these tables.

I have set up a relationship between both of the tables as they will both contain the user's account numbers.

I'm just not sure how to go about it and would really appreciate the help. I am currently using Microsoft Access 2007.

Answer (score 0):

for your second table you need to use a new primary key like "customerInformationID". Reference the customer table by a foreign key. 
Then you can join these tables like this:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Number, ci.notes
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN customerInformation AS ci ON c.customerID = ci.customerID
```

Why do you need two tables anyways? If you don't need them for a technical purpose like "every user shall be able to store his own notes to a customer" then you can also store them in your main table as all of these information are only dependent from the primary key.

Best Regards
Bruellhusten

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply.

I will need to be able to create a note for any user at any point in time, save the date in which the note was logged etc. then be able to search and filter that information at a later date.

Comment: Also forgive my ignorance, where would i write that code exactly?

Comment: Easiest way would be a subform in your form and enter the SELECT statement as the source. Then switch the subform to a Data Grid and you should have a table with all the information. If it is for multiple users you will also need a foreign key column in your customerInformation table referencing the user.

Comment: maybe start with some tutorials on MS Access. It is not intuitive at all. And it is a long way to get used to all "specialties" [link]http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/forms-i-create-a-form-to-enter-and-view-your-data-RZ001027863.aspx[/link]

Comment: yeah i was thinking of putting that code on the button, so when it presses then thats when it would run that code. makes sense right?

Comment: I would be careful about assigning code to buttons and other controls.  If you ever have to change something the first question you'll have is, "where's my darn code?"  You might want to put all your code in a module and call the applicable functions from your form controls.

Comment: @DanBracuk Seems like hard work to me. There is nothing wrong with using form and control events. If you copy a form to another database the code goes with it. I would only use a Function if I knew that it was code I could re-use elsewhere.